# Solve gives conditional expression involving C[1]

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function u:

```
-Log[9 - 8 E^(-c + t)]
```

I need to find the value of `c` that makes this function zero:

```
Solve[u[0] == 0, c]
```

I get back a strange conditional expression:

```
{{c -> ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

I don't know what C[1] is, but I am wondering why there is a condition at all; It is obvious that there is a solution -Log[9/8]. Yet this does not show up in the output from Solve

Comment: `C[1]` is a constant in the Integers.  It means that if (the condition) C[1] is an integer you have multiple solutions where `C[1] = 1, 2, ...`.  By the way:  You should define `u[t]`.

Comment: Never mind this comment

Comment: But isn't 2 i \Pi just unity?

Comment: Of course not!  And you want $2 i \pi\ 47$ anyway... (or $2 i \pi\ 48$ or any other integer).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you only want a real solution:

```
u[t_] := -Log[9 - 8 E^(-c + t)]

Solve[u[0] == 0, c, Reals]
```

> {{c -> 0}}

The reason that complex solutions exist is because of the identity:

```
Simplify[
    Exp[2 I n Pi] == 1,
    n ∈ Integers
]
```

> True

so adding `2 I n Pi` to `c` is also a solution. Finally, your supposed solution `-Log[9/8]` is not a solution, `Log[1]` is 0, and solving `9 - 8 E^-c == 1` yields the real solution `c=0`.